# Video Not found while add Vimeo video in magento 2

Tags: magento2, video

When I am trying to add video using Vimeo URL that time alert message comes.
so please give me a better solution.

Comment: Can you please post the error message

Comment: Attention

Error: "Video not found"  <=== already mentioned sir. thanks

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me on version 2.3.4

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/f2231f8d953bb650c3462a824716fd8972c6bb6c

Answer (score 0):

What magento2 version are you using? Just pasted this Vimeo video url in a Magento 2.3.1 and works perfectly: https://player.vimeo.com/video/298200022

That url comes from the sharing Iframe box, check the image:

[image]

It seems that some vimeo videos are available trough the api and some others aren't, for example:

This video is not available through the url Magento2 uses to get it: 
https://player.vimeo.com/video/295556470 
Magento calls: https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/295556470.json 
**curl -I https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/295556470.json == 404 Not Fount**

This other one is available:
 
https://player.vimeo.com/video/298200022 
Magento calls: https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/298200022.json 
**curl -I https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/298200022.json == 200 OK**

If we use a video that returns a 404 the message Video Not Found is then triggered, so you have to make sure the video you are trying to use is available through the Api, probably this is a setting for the video in Vimeo

Comment: Yes i did that but still not works.

Comment: what is your magento version? did you try with a different video?

Comment: Version Magento 2.3.1  and yes I tried sir

Comment: Try adding some breakpoints in this file which is the one throwing the error:

vendor/magento/module-product-video/view/adminhtml/web/js/get-video-information.js

Comment: Thank you I will check it, sir

Comment: yes, I have been facing the same issue on magento2.3.5-p1 EE can you advise?

Comment: @NagarajuK this issue is not related with magento, you should check the video conditions in vimeo, check with curl the response